# Can't save the session of Whatsapp web with Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I want to save session of whatsapp web so I do not have to scan qr-code every time I open whatsapp web. I use:

```cs
options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + FolderPathToStoreSession)
```

but the `qr-code` appear again.
Here is the method to open whatsapp web for first time to scan qr code and save it to folder:

```cs
public static int OpenNewChrome(
        string Website,
        int TimeToWaitInMinutes,
        string FolderPathToStoreSession)
{
    ChromeOptions options = null;
    ChromeDriver driver = null;
    try
    {
        //chrome process id
        int ProcessId = -1;
        //time to wait until open chrome
        var TimeToWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeToWaitInMinutes);
        ChromeDriverService cService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        //hide dos screen
        cService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        options = new ChromeOptions();
        //session file directory
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + FolderPathToStoreSession);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(cService, options, TimeToWait);

        //set process id of chrome
        ProcessId = cService.ProcessId;

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Website);

        FRM_MSG f2 = new FRM_MSG();
        DialogResult r = f2.ShowDLG(" ",
             "Did you successfully finish scan bardcode?",
               FRM_MSG.MSGIcon.Question,
               FRM_MSG.BTNS.Two,
               new string[] { "Yes Finish", "Cannot scan qr-code" });

        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
        if (r == DialogResult.Yes)
            return ProcessId;
        return -1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
        driver = null;
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and here is method to restore session:

```cs
public static int OpenOldChrome(
       string Website,
       int TimeToWaitInMinutes,
       string FolderPathToStoreSession)
{
    ChromeOptions options = null;
    ChromeDriver driver = null;
    try
    {
        //chrome process id
        int ProcessId = -1;
        //time to wait until open chrome
        var TimeToWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeToWaitInMinutes);
        ChromeDriverService cService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

        //hide dos screen
        cService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        options = new ChromeOptions();

        //session file directory
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + FolderPathToStoreSession);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(cService, options, TimeToWait);

        //set process id of chrome
        ProcessId = cService.ProcessId;

        Thread.Sleep(50000);

        FRM_MSG f2 = new FRM_MSG();
        DialogResult r = f2.ShowDLG(" ",
             "Did you wnat to exit?",
               FRM_MSG.MSGIcon.Question,
               FRM_MSG.BTNS.Two,
               new string[] { "Yes", "No" });

        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
        if (r == DialogResult.Yes)
            return ProcessId;

        return -1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
        driver = null;
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The problem as I said the qr-code appear again, I want to scan qr-code only once
I use google chrome version 74, web driver v 3.141.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do check if the profile folder is correct . An old thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver-using-java) mention that you need to add \Default to the profile path.

Have you try adding this to see if this helps

```
options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions")
```

Comment: I use options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions") and it worked fine Thans so much